# What are the programming languages for stalking facebook friends

Tags: facebook, programming-languages

I would like your guidance. Could you suggest me a programming languages capable of monitoring my Facebook friends activity? 
By activity I mean:

- Know when they get online
- Know when they post something
- Know which are my friends that contribute more in likes/comments in my profile in the last *X* hour

Comment: Why the hate? Isn't this a plausible question to ask?

Comment: first of all: too broad for stackoverflow. you are required to add what you have tried so far. that being said: what you want to achieve is not possible at all. there would only be one way (scraping), but that´s not allowed on facebook. not sure why someone would seriously ask for help in "stalking", to be honest...

Comment: "stalking" was sarcarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could think of following two ways:

- You will need to use Facebook Graph API to monitor posts by user https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/post. But for that, the user should give permission to your app or the post should be public. Graph API SDK is available for PHP, Javascript, Android, and IOS.
- Another way I could think is by using automation testing tool like [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/). Selenium is available in Java, C#, Ruby, Python, and Javascript. You will need to write Selenium code to open Facebook, log in to your account and check the status of your friends. To do this you will need to either keep your system running or use a headless browser and host it on a server.

I hope you are not doing this to spam or annoy people on Facebook.

Comment: you hope has been listened. It is for good use